# How to pass multiple parameters to a function from HTML during Onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to pass 3 arguments to a function from HTML by ID during Onclick

```
onclick="total(document.getElementById('start').value,document.getElementById('finish').value,document.getElementById('break').value)"
```

but this is giving me an error

> total is not a function
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (auth.html:42) onclick @ auth.html:42

Comment: Where is your "total" function defined? What is it made of?

Comment: if you have the id's of the elements. Why do you want to pass it in? Just do this in your onclick function!

Comment: Passing parameters has nothing to do with error shown. The function itself is not defined in window scope. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: The error basically means that javascript does not know what to do when you use the function `total()` because this function hasn't been defined.

Comment: i have defined it in .js file `function total(inputa,inputb,inputc)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you pickup the dom values in the function.

```
onclick="total()"

function total()
{
    var inputa = document.getElementById('start').value;
    var inputb = document.getElementById('finish').value;
    var inputc = document.getElementById('break').value;
}
```

Comment: This is a good recommendation, but not an answer. The OP will still get the exact same error with your answer. However, once the issue is solved, it's recommended to follow your answer. Consider adding some explanation about that.